# Yii2 MySQL how to prevent duplicate select query

Tags: mysql, yii2-advanced-app

I saw in my debug menu that I have some duplicate select queries. In particular, this is the one that I got 4 times `SELECT * FROM page_adminlang WHERE (language=bg) AND (page_id=1)` in 4 different files. Is there a right way to prevent such situations and is this big hit on the site speed performance? Shall I retrieve the row in some variable like `$page = PageAdmin::findOne(1)` and than call it where I need and is this the right way? I red other articles but they were mainly for duplicate rows on insertion. Not familiar with MySQL performance tuning but want to go deeper in this area.Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you recognize the query? Do you know where it is in the code?

Comment: Yes, I know where it is.

Comment: Jairus Martin beat me to it; look into query caching but also data caching.

Comment: Yes. It is what I'm looking for. Thank you both of you. Now the problem is that I can't enable memcached on xampp ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50424502/installing-memcached-on-xampp-v3-2-2
p.s. I'm planning to move to Linux already ...

Comment: Remember that you don't necessarily need memcached on your local machine. You could just use Filecache locally and memcached on the production server. The only thing you have to change is the config between environments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1 - Configure MemCache Component**

An Easier method is to enable db caching, then it won't matter, put a 5second duration at first.

In your component db connection settings set the following properties:

```
'components' => [
    'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'password',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        ....
        'enableQueryCache' => true,
        'queryCacheDuration' => 5, // five seconds
        ....
    ]
]
```

See:

1. https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/caching-data
2. https://www2.0/yii-db.yiiframework.com/doc/api/-connection

**Option 2 - Custom query with cache**

```
public function getResults()
{
    // Cache expires every x seconds (60sec/min * 60min/hr * 6hrs)
    $duration = 60*60*6; 
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM some_table";
    
    return Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql_query)->cache($duration)->queryAll();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't usually face that issue, but if I have to retrieve something from the database multiple times (and I know that won't change), I do something like that in my model

```
private $_myData = null;
public function getMyData() {
    if ($this->_myData !== null) return $this->_myData;

    $this->_myData = //query your data;
    return $this->getMyData();
}
```